# Sum of infinitely many i.i.d. random variables is infinite with probability 1

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

How do I solve this? I'm really confused.

> If $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ are non-negative independently and identically distributed random variables with $P(X_i>0)>0$, show that $\displaystyle P\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty X_i=\infty\right)=1$.

Comment: I know I have to show that there exists a t such that the event {Xi > t} occurs for infinitely many i but I don't know how to show that.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I've updated your title to be more descriptive--descriptive titles are very helpful when scanning through a list of questions to see what they are about.  Also, it is customary to show your effort and work so far on a question, if you can.

Comment: @user126310 Have you learned about the [second Borel-Cantelli lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result)?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** It suffices to show for each $n$ that $$P\bigg\{\omega:\sum_{i=1}^\infty X_i(\omega)>n\bigg\}=1,$$ which is the case iff for all $0<\delta<1$
$$P\bigg\{\omega:\sum_{i=1}^\infty X_i(\omega)>n\bigg\}>\delta.$$ There is $\epsilon>0$ such that $P(X_i>\epsilon)>0$.

Now for each $m$ we have $$P\bigg\{\omega:\sum_{i=1}^m X_i(\omega)>n\bigg\}\leq P\bigg\{\omega:\sum_{i=1}^\infty X_i(\omega)>n\bigg\},$$ so it suffices to show, using the $\epsilon$, that for some $m$ large enough, $$P\bigg\{\omega:\sum_{i=1}^m X_i(\omega)>n\bigg\}>\delta,$$
which is an elementary argument. Try it.